# how do i tag/define the sections and section titles to be expressed in the sheet and not pulled through as a line of data?

Tags: google-sheets

I have no idea if what I need is possible but if anyone can assist me in how I can accomplish what I need please can you assist.

I have a google sheet that lists products across franchises, I need to create a single sheet that pulls through the data from all specified sheets. Easy enough. It gets complicated because i have a additional formatting within the sheets that need to be expressed in data.

EG:
Sheet name = Franchise
Section name = Type of good
sub section = Model

Then all other lines are additional data.

My question how do i tag/define the sections and section titles to be expressed in the sheet and not pulled through as a line of data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.